# Regex to replace everything outside start and end tags in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have defined my Start and End Tags like for strings

```
!R= //Start Tag of R
=R! //End Tag of R

!G= //Start Tag of G
=G! //End Tag of G
```

And I want to replace everything (string) outside these two tags. Suppose my string is like

```
<div>
   I am going to be replaced
   !R= Hello World =R!
   I am being replaced
   !G= I will be safe =G!
   I have replaced
</div>
```

I don't need any indentations just replaced everything outside my defined tags. Output can be something like this

```
@<div>
   I am going to be replaced@
   !R= Hello World =R!
   @I am being replaced@
   !G= I will be safe =G!
   @I have replaced
</div>@
```

Currently I am doing it with some sort of jugars like

```
$str  = '!N-'.$str.'-N!';
$str = str_replace(array('!R-', '-R!'), array('-N!!R-', '-R!!N-'), $str);   
$str = preg_replace_callback("~!N-(.+?)-N!~s", function($matches) 
{
    return str_replace('!N-'.$matches[1].'-N!', "@a" . $matches[1] . "@a", $matches[0]);
}, $str);

$str = str_replace(array('!N-','-N!'), '', $str);
```

This works just great but it is taking 0.12 seconds for one single string :(

Comment: Can you post the expected result? Should it include `<div>`, `</div>` etc.?

Comment: -1 Duplicate of your **own** question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811520/regex-to-replace-everything-outside-defined-tags-in-php

Comment: @cept0 This isn't a duplicate. See [comment 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811520/regex-to-replace-everything-outside-defined-tags-in-php#comment33009967_21811520), [comment 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811520/regex-to-replace-everything-outside-defined-tags-in-php#comment33010031_21811520).

Comment: @AmalMurali see expected output. I am totally blank at Regex

Comment: Please guys look at my problem before it is closed or removed :(

Comment: @JohnSmith Can I get my share ? I mean you're getting paid to do this ... Anyways, use [this](http://regex101.com/r/iU1qK3), the first part is to ignore the tags, the second part is to match everything else. Have fun and promise me to learn regex :)

Comment: hahahahahahaah sure for sharing my salary and learning regex. Let me see. But I would ask you to post as answer so I can happily accept and vote it

Comment: i don't know why but it is not working as $str = preg_replace_callback("/(?:!R=.*?=R!|!G=.*?=G!)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.*?(?=(?:!R=.*?=R!|!G=.*?=G!)|$)/xgs", function($matches) 
 {
  return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
 }, $str);

Comment: @JohnSmith There is no `g` modifier in PHP. The online demo uses `g` because it needs a way to tell it to match/replace all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like I'm overcomplicating things with my [first regex](http://regex101.com/r/iU1qK3). Just use this one:

```
(.+?)            # Match anything one or more times ungreedy (group 1)
(?:              # Non-capturing group
   (             # Group 2, here we add our exceptions
      !R=.*?=R!
      |
      !G=.*?=G!
   )             # End group 2
   |             # Or
   $             # End of line
)                # End of non-capturing group
```

Do not forget to use these modifiers

- `x` : For formatting and comments.
- `s` : To match newlines with `.` (dot).

Replace with `@$1@$2`.

In PHP it would look like:

```
$input = '<div>
   I am going to be replaced
   !R= Hello World =R!
   I am being replaced
   !G= I will be safe =G!
   I have replaced
</div>';

$regex = '~
(.+?)            # Match anything one or more times ungreedy (group 1)
(?:              # Non-capturing group
   (             # Group 2, here we add our exceptions
      !R=.*?=R!
      |
      !G=.*?=G!
   )             # End group 2
   |             # Or
   $             # End of line
)                # End of non-capturing group
~xs';
$output = preg_replace($regex, '@$1@$2', $input);

echo $output;
```

You have promised me to learn regex. I look forward to it.
<sub>Mwa</sub>ha<sup>ha</sup><sup><sup>ha</sup><sup><sup>ha</sup></sup></sup>

Enough of laughing, here's an <kbd>[**online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vO6zT8)</kbd>.

Comment: Hamza it is retrieving string inside these tags but I want outside of these tags as I have said in my question

Comment: it feels like Shame :( I have never asked that much

Comment: This deserves a `+1` just for the ***"Mwa ha ha ha ha"*** ;-)

Comment: @JohnSmith I do not see the problem ? Here's an [online php demo](https://eval.in/102162). The trick is to match both and then capture the exceptions and put them back in the replacement string.

Comment: Hamza your regex outputs **!R= Hello World =R!\n!G= I will be safe =G!\n\n** while i want to output **<div>I am going to be replaced I am being replaced I have replaced</div>** leaving out these tags and whatever inside them

Comment: regexes shouldn't being used to parse html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: WOW Man thanks Thanks thanksss Alot buddy. I have never seen such a kind helper like you. This works like charm. Kiss you. Thanks Alot. I cannot believe you helped that much

Comment: @hek2mgl If you are referring to the top voted answer there, then please have a look at [this meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182189). Also this isn't really about HTML parsing, we've got custom delimiters. If you know an html parser that can do this, then be my guest :)

Comment: @JohnSmith & HamZa, wouldn't [this](http://regex101.com/r/eZ8gZ0) be just a *little* better? :)

Comment: Hamza why converts everything into one line instead maintaining line breaks?

Comment: @Hamza No, I just refer to what my experience tells me, although I like that answer of course. :) Maybe I failed to get the problem here, as I've answered the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811520/regex-to-replace-everything-outside-defined-tags-in-php) wich was definitely not a job for a regex. imo

Comment: @Jerry your code is same like hamza has suggested and this also converts whole string into one single line instead not maintaining line breaks

Comment: @JohnSmith I really don't see how you can get a single line with the code ([see code demo](http://ideone.com/IODRxh)). The regex is not exactly the same, it has a few more things which place the `@` differently.

Comment: @HamZa Thanks again for your such a nice support I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a slightly simpler regex:

```
$str = '
<div>
   I am going to be replaced
   !R= Hello World =R!
   I am being replaced
   !G= I will be safe =G!
   I have replaced
</div>
';

$regex = '/(\s*!(.+)=[^=]*=\2!\s*)/';

$result = '@' . preg_replace($regex, '@\1@', trim($str)) . '@';
$result = str_replace('@@', '', $result);
echo $result;
```